# SailsJs "manually" model creation

Tags: node.js, orm, ldap, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to create a User model in SailsJs that will hold the user information from an LDAP repository. There isn't any ldap adapter implemented so I'm wondering if it is possible to use this model without any connection or adapater?
This is my model definition:  User.js

```
module.exports = {
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  migrate: 'safe',
  schema: true,

  attributes: {
    userId: {
      type: 'string',
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      columnName: 'inum',
      required: true
    },
    displayName: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'displayName',
      required: true
    },
    userName: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'uid',
      required: true
    },
    emailAddress: {
      type: 'email',
      columnName: 'mail',
      required: true
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'phoneNumberVerified',
      required: false
    }
  }
}
```

is there a way to manually create a new User object and trigger the ORM validations without having an underlying connection and adapter?

(I tried creating a custom ldap adapter but I couldn't find any good guidance on how to do so)

Comment: Have you ever tried `passport-ldapauth`? Please have a look at:  https://github.com/briepace/sails-auth-example

Comment: thanks! Actually I'm using openId/connect for authentication, but users are stored on LDAP.